# How to automatically start TightVNC server as root on Ubuntu startup?

Tags: ubuntu, vnc

How can this be achieved? I want to boot the headless Ubuntu 14.04 box and have it start TightVNC as root.

Comment: That does not start the server on Ubuntu 14.04, which uses Upstart @GAD3R

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if this is too late.
Put this in `/lib/systemd/system/x11vnc.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start x11vnc at startup.
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -auth guess -forever -loop -noxdamage -repeat -rfbauth /home/USERNAME/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5900 -shared

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Replacing "USERNAME" with your username.

Then do `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and `sudo systemctl enable x11vnc.service`.
I think it will start on the next boot.

([Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers#Have_x11vnc_start_automatically_via_systemd_in_any_environment_.28Vivid.2B-.29))